# Windows timezone

Tags: windows, time, timezone

In Windows, we can change timezone easily. But I have one question. In the dropdown list, there are several options for the same timezone. For example, for UTC+8, we can see these options:
(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqng, ...
(UTC+08:00) Irkutsk
(UTC+08:00) Kula Lumpur, Singapore, ...
...
I know we can choose different options in different cities. But are there any other differences besides the city names? Are there any other meanings for making different options just for one timezone?

Comment: Perhaps they have different daylight savings rules?

Answer (score 4):

When time-zones are split like that, it's generally because there are subtle differences, generally in the daylight-savings-time boundaries, that require it. There may be one universal UCT+8 time-zone, but tens to hundreds of localities with different DST traditions. Not all of them get a time-zone in Windows, but the big national/state zones do.